# How much to support a big model?

Tags: sets

Exactly, how many LEGO blocks would somebody need to support a model that weighs 30 pounds?

Comment: 30 grams? I think pretty much anything bigger than a Lego flower stem would handle that...

Comment: oh oof wait wrong mueasure cRAP-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 . According to [experimental results](https://gizmodo.com/how-tall-can-a-lego-tower-be-before-it-crushes-itself-5965451), a single Lego 2x2 brick can support about 950 pounds before failing.

This does not take the shape of the model into account - if you have a sharp point going down into the brick, it's probably going to fail a bit more quickly!